# How to get Selected Value from DevExpress RepositoryItemLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have 1 DevExpress.XtraBars.Bar control in the form. I have Added 1 RepositoryItemLookUpEdit on that menu Bar  now I want to get selected value on 1 button Click event

```
 private void barButtonItem2_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(lkpReportName.EditValue!=null)
        {

        }
    }
```

It gives error

> Error 42  'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit' does not contain a definition for 'EditValue' and no extension method 'EditValue' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: EditValue is a property in BarEdititem which is the container for your RepositoryItemLookupEdit

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič thanks that's right if You can post answer then i will mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RepositoryItemLookUpEdit` itself doesn't have this property. However, you can access the selected value via `EditValue` property of `BarEditValue` - which is the container for your `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit`.